# How to column bind and row bind a large number of data frames in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data set of vehicles. They were recorded every 0.1 seconds so there IDs repeat in Vehicle ID column. In total there are 2169 vehicles. I filtered the 'Vehicle velocity' column for every vehicle (using for loop) which resulted in a new column with first and last 30 values removed (per vehicle) . In order to bind it with original data frame, I removed the first and last 30 values of table too and then using cbind() combined them. This works for one last vehicle. I want this smoothing and column binding for all vehicles and finally I want to combine all the data frames of vehicles into one single table. That means rowbinding in sequence of vehicle IDs. This is what I wrote so far:

```
traj1 <- read.csv('trajectories-0750am-0805am.txt', sep='   ', header=F)
head(traj1)
names (traj1)<-c('Vehicle ID', 'Frame ID','Total Frames', 'Global Time','Local X', 'Local Y', 'Global X','Global Y','Vehicle Length','Vehicle width','Vehicle class','Vehicle velocity','Vehicle acceleration','Lane','Preceding Vehicle ID','Following Vehicle ID','Spacing','Headway')

# TIME COLUMN
Time <- sapply(traj1$'Frame ID', function(x) x/10)
traj1$'Time' <- Time


# SMOOTHING VELOCITY
smooth <- function (x, D, delta){
z <- exp(-abs(-D:D/delta))
r <- convolve (x, z, type='filter')/convolve(rep(1, length(x)),z,type='filter')
r
}

for (i in unique(traj1$'Vehicle ID')){
veh <- subset (traj1, traj1$'Vehicle ID'==i)
svel <- smooth(veh$'Vehicle velocity',30,10)
svel <- data.frame(svel)
veh <- head(tail(veh, -30), -30)
fta <- cbind(veh,svel)
}
```

'fta' now only shows the data frame for last vehicle. But I want all data frames (for all vehicles 'i') combined by row. May be for loop is not the right way to do it but I don't know how can I use tapply (or any other apply function) to do so many things same time.

## EDIT

I can't reproduce my dataset here but 'Orange' data set in R could provide good analogy. Using the same smoothing function, the for loop would look like this (if 'age' column is smoothed and 'Tree' column is equivalent to my 'Vehicle ID' coulmn):

```
for (i in unique(Orange$Tree)){
tre <- subset (Orange, Orange$'Tree'==i)
age2 <- round(smooth(tre$age,2,0.67),digits=2)
age2 <- data.frame(age2)
tre <- head(tail(tre, -2), -2)
comb <- cbind(tre,age2)}
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data so we can run your code? Also, take advantage of r's vectorization; for example, you can calculate your time as `traj1$Time <- traj1$'Frame ID' / 10`

Comment: The closer the words `cbind` and `large number` get together, the more likely the world is to explode spontaneously (don't panic!).  I strongly suggest you pre-allocate the results matrix and fill it in, rather than severely fragmenting your memory.

Comment: @rawr Thanks, that is a good idea. +Ari B. Friedman, what do you mean by 'pre-allocate the results matrix and fill it in'?

Comment: Your example code doesn't work -- in addition to the extra }, the call to `smooth` yields an error.

Comment: @josilber, he has defined the function smooth above.

Comment: Pre-allocating means that you create an object in which to store the results of your loop, knowing the dimensions you need beforehand, and filling in the object as the loop goes on so that r doesn't keep a growing object in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umair, I am not sure I understood what you want.

If I understood right, you want to combine all the results by row. To do that you could save all the results in a list and then `do.call` an `rbind`:

```
comb <- list() ### create list to save the results
length(comb) <- length(unique(Orange$Tree))

##Your loop for smoothing:

for (i in 1:length(unique(Orange$Tree))){
  tre <- subset (Orange, Tree==unique(Orange$Tree)[i])
  age2 <- round(smooth(tre$age,2,0.67),digits=2)
  age2 <- data.frame(age2)
  tre <- head(tail(tre, -2), -2)
  comb[[i]] <- cbind(tre,age2) ### save results in the list
}

final.data<-do.call("rbind", comb) ### combine all results by row
```

This will give you:

```
 Tree  age circumference    age2
3     1  664            87  687.88
4     1 1004           115  982.66
5     1 1231           120 1211.49
10    2  664           111  687.88
11    2 1004           156  982.66
12    2 1231           172 1211.49
17    3  664            75  687.88
18    3 1004           108  982.66
19    3 1231           115 1211.49
24    4  664           112  687.88
25    4 1004           167  982.66
26    4 1231           179 1211.49
31    5  664            81  687.88
32    5 1004           125  982.66
33    5 1231           142 1211.49
```

Just for fun, a different way to do it using `plyr::ddply` and `sapply` with `split`:

```
library(plyr)
data<-ddply(Orange, .(Tree), tail, n=-2)
data<-ddply(data, .(Tree), head, n=-2)
data<- cbind(data, 
             age2=matrix(sapply(split(Orange$age, Orange$Tree), smooth, D=2, delta=0.67), ncol=1, byrow=FALSE))
```

Comment: also, `length(comb) <- length(unique(Orange$Tree))`